# SSO SharePoint 2010 through ASP.NET MVC3-Application, Document Editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, single-sign-on

We have a ASP.NET MVC3-Application which includes a lot of links to Documents in SharePoint 2010 - Libraries. If the User clicks on one of these links, he'll be invited to choose between ReadOnly-Mode or Edit-Mode of the Office-Document. If he chooses "Edit-Mode", he will have to enter the credentials for SharePoint.
Is it possible to do some kind of SingleSignOn out of the MVC-Application, using the Users MVC-App-Creentials to log into SharePoint2010? We'd like to have the user clicked on the link and to be able to edit the document and click save (saving back to SharePoint) without entering his credentials once again. Are there any experiences?

//edit: the MVC-Application & SharePoint are both in a different Active Directory than the User, so this problem is not solvable by implementing a User > SharePoint SSO. Further it is not possible to access SharePoint through the SharePoint Server Object Model in the MVC3-Application: SharePoint uses .NET 3.5 and MVC3 requires .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are trying to do, however, you would need to enable claims based suthentication on SharePoint and write a [custom provider](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/03/13/writing-a-custom-claims-provider-for-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions in your case is Active Directory Federation Services.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/andrew/archive/2010/06/09/what-is-adfs-and-why-you-should-care.aspx